# What is the closest way of writing a C++ std::reverse equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, algorithm

The `reverse` algorithm in the C++ standard library is equivalent to

```
template <class BidirectionalIterator>
  void reverse (BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last)
{
  while ((first!=last)&&(first!=--last)) {
    std::iter_swap (first,last);
    ++first;
  }
}
```

according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/. I want to write the equivalent in C#:

```
public void Reverse<T> ( T first, T last ) 
{
    // ... 
}
```

First of all, how do you pass in two references to `IEnumerator`s, with the second being one that can travel backwards? Is there a natural way of doing this or does it require first extending `IEnumerable<T>`?

Second of all, if the answer to the previous question is no, then is there a Skeet-certified C# way of writing `reverse` that equals the C++ one in terms of generality and effeciency? If so, what is it?

Comment: Maybe this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451099/implementing-a-bidirectional-enumerator-in-c-sharp) and @Brian Murphy-Booth answer is helpfull for you. To answer your question, C# has no bidirectional iterators

Comment: When you iterate in C++ you have a first and a last. In C# this concept doesn't exist. You iterate fully the collection...

Comment: And there is a LINQ [`Enumerable.Reverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `List<T>` interface provides a `Reverse()` method which will do the same as C++ equivapent.

Have a look https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think you meant to link [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf2ay11y(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. And this only answers the efficiency part of their question, not the generality part.